# Android: changing the order of views causes "Unfortunately, app has stopped" OK. Why?

Tags: android, layout, view, emulation

I have an application called "Yamba". The only layout XML file it has is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/titleStatus"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/hintText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textCounter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttonUpdate"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The application shows everything well.

The only change I made is changing the order of (`EditText` id/editText") with (`TextView` id/textCounter) so that it becomes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/titleStatus"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textCounter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="000" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/hintText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttonUpdate"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

After this change the emulator shows me: `Unfortunately, Yamba has stopped" OK`.
When I restore it back to its previous order, everything works well. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change the order of Views in the XML layout, their numerical IDs are changed (they are assigned from top to bottom), then when you refer to the previous ID in your code for example in `findViewById()` you'll get the wrong one and an `ClassCastException` (I guess because you didn't include the logcat).

Cleaning before building will solve the problem.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. Much more then my theory of eclipse being possessed. +1.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt with things that don't make sense. Project Clean/Exit eclipse and reopen.

I've encounter strange things like this before and that's ultimately what solved it.